# Square wave 40kHz with ATtiny10

Tags: attiny

I'm using a 12 MHz ATtiny10 and I would like to generate a square wave on PB0 at 40 kHz. I think that I need CTC. What should be the values of TCCR0A, TCCR0B, OCR0A and OCR0B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square wave at 40 kHz toggles every 12.5 us, which is exactly 150 oscillator clock periods. The code is:

```
TCCR0A = COM0A(0x01); //Toggle OC0A on compare match
TCCR0B = WGM0_32(0x01) | CS0(1); //clear on compare with OCR0A, use unscaled system clock
OCR0A = (12000000ul/40000u/2u)-1u; //overflow twice per 40kHz period
```

Comment: It's definitely working. I'm wondering if it would be possible to output on a second pin the exact same signal BUT inverted?